# Tailwindcss - Pagination shows above the table

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

The problem I'm encountering is that the pagination is appearing above the table, whereas my expectation is for it to be displayed after the table. Ideally, when I add multiple rows, the pagination should follow immediately after the table.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/3Q9D3mnnnn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvLMr.png)

Comment: By removing ```absolute``` in your div class of table will move the pagination below the table, so do ```<div class="w-full overflow-x-auto">``` instead of ```<div class="absolute w-full overflow-x-auto">```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to give this `absolute` class to the following div `<div class="absolute w-full overflow-x-auto">`? When I removed it, the pagination showed under the table.

Comment: Yes, If I remove that means, table grows more and appear out side the window also.

Comment: @R.Elavarasan No, you definitively _don't_ want to position that element absolute. That takes your whole table out of the normal layout flow, which _causes_ your issue of the pagination moving up here to begin with. (Because from its perspective, the table doesn't occupy any space any more, it's as if that table wasn't there at all in the first place.) Whatever your problem with the table in normal flow is - you need to find a different solution to that, than positioning this element absolute.

Answer (score 0):

All that I did was removed the pagination div from where it was earlier nd added it inside the same div as table and it met the rqirements.

```
<div>
                        <div class="relative">
                            <div class="absolute w-full overflow-x-auto">
                                <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
                                    <thead
                                        class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
                                        <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
                                            <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600 w-96">
                                                Name</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Mobile Number</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Employee Id</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Branch</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Department</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Shift</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Staff Category</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Designation</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Date of Joining</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Resignation Date</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Role</th>
                                            <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                                                Company</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="sticky left-0 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                                <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                                                    <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
                                                        src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="">
                                                    <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John Doe</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="p-4">9192939494</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">NA-1362</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">Sengodampalayam</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">Tele Calling 1</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">Regular Shift</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">Permanant</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">Senior Telecaller</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">28-07-2023</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">-</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">Branch Manager</td>
                                            <td class="p-4">XYZ India Private Limited</td>
                                        </tr>
    
                                        <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
                                        
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="flex justify-center mt-4 mb-20">
                            <nav class="relative z-0 inline-flex -space-x-px shadow-sm" aria-label="Pagination">
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-left -->
                                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                        fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                            d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                                            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    1
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    2
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative items-center hidden px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 md:inline-flex hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    3
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    4
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    5
                                </a>
                                <a href="#"
                                    class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-100">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-right -->
                                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                        fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                            d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                                            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
```

Comment: If I add like this means, the scroll bar is shown after the pagination. If the scroll bar is moved from left to right means, pagination also scrolls and pagination is hidden.